# Why is my makefile recompiling even if I just compiled the source?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a simple makefile that compiles a `p.c` file to an executable using `gcc` on Linux.
The `p.c` file depends on a `a.h` file.
My makefile looks like this:

```
//makefile
CC = gcc

build: p.c a.h
    $(CC) -o out p.c
clean:
    rm -f *.exe
rebuild: clean build
```

Comment: What's the invocation of `make`?

Comment: One small point: `make clean` will not work as you are trying to delete a '`.exe`' file, and your executable has no such extension.

Comment: 'The p.c file depends on a a.h file' ... this is not true. **out** depends on a.h, as well as p.c, but your makefile doesn't say so.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the invocation of make is ... no invocation will get the right result.

Comment: @LeeNetherton, so the only way to clean it is to specifically remove the executable file with it's name?

Comment: @learner, if you don't have extension you should specify the name. this is a hack `find . -perm +100 -type f -delete`

Comment: @learner: The best way of doing this would be to combine Maxim Yegorushkin's answer with some local variables to hold your executable's name. I will write another answer with an example of what I mean...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your makefile doesn't produce the files it promises to produce, namely `build`, `clean` and `rebuild`. Since these targets are not files they should be marked as [phony targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets):

```
.PHONY: build clean rebuild
```

`build` target should be:

```
build : out

out : p.c a.h
    $(CC) -o $@ p.c
```

Comment: You don't need .PHONY unless you have files named build, clean, or rebuild laying around.

Comment: @learner: [$@](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_0040_0040-_0040r_007b_0028automatic-variable_0029_007d-939)

Comment: @learner That refers to the target, in this case `out`; it just allows you to avoid explicit mention of it. It is more useful in better structured Makefiles, like `out: a.h ... out: p.c ... $(CC) -o $@ $^` where the command to be executed doesn't depend on the names of files at all.

Comment: @JimBalter: I once debugged for an hour why my `clean` target didn't work. Turned out there was a file named `clean` and my `clean` target wasn't marked as `.PHONY`. Kind of makes one appreciate `.PHONY`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Like I said, "unless you have files named ... clean ... laying around". Me, I would avoid that ... but then, I wrote Makefiles for a decade before .PHONY existed.

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
build: p.c a.h
    $(CC) -o out p.c
```

says "I'm compiling with $(CC) -o out p.c and the result will be a file named 'build'". Since you lied to `make` (this creates the `out` file instead), it will try building 'build' again.

There's a lesson for Makefile writers here: always use the `$@` variable (denoting the target) to avoid this error:

```
out: p.c a.h
    $(CC) -o $@ p.c
```

For more advice, see [Paul's Rules for Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

Learner, here is an example of using a variable to store the name of the executable. This way you only need to specify it in one place at the start of your Makefile:

```
EXECUTABLE = out

.PHONY: build clean rebuild

build: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): p.c a.h
    $(CC) -o $@ p.c

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)

rebuild: clean build
```

Normally you would also have your `.c` and `.h` files listed in variables too so that you can add/remove files from your build easily without having to search through your Makefile for all of the places that they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles have the general syntax:

```
target : dependencies
    commands to make target from dependencies
```

So your Makefile expects to make a file called `build` using the `build : p.c a.h` target.
Since the commands don't actually make this file each time you call make it's having to redo the command.

(PS: Linux binaries don't have a .exe extension)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid always recompiling the source, then your target should depend on the *object* file, not the source file:

```
target.exe : p.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $?; 

p.o: p.c a.h
        $(CC) -c $@ $?;
```

A typical makefile doesn't usually have an explicit rule per object file, nor does it usually list explicit dependencies between implementation and header files; you usually see an implicit rule like

```
%.o : %.c 
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $?;
```

(where `$?` indicates the list of prerequisites for that target) or, if your project is dead simple (one source file), you don't even need that; you can usually get away with

all: target
target: target.o

assuming you have a file named `target.c`, the above will build `target` using the default compiler and CFLAGS options.

Likewise, a typical makefile (at least in my experience) doesn't explicitly list header dependencies; rather, it relies on a compiler option to generate those dependency lists automagically (for gcc, that option is `-M`).  See [here](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood that it is necessary for the 'target' and 'output file' names to match fully for the *make* to be able to recognize if recompilation is not required. So in case of Windows environment (as *make* I have tried `mingw32-make.exe`) it should be like this:

```
build.exe: p.c a.h
    gcc -o build.exe p.c
```

or

```
build.exe: p.c a.h
    gcc -o build p.c    # .exe is added automatically to generated file
```

This code will lead to recompilation always when *make* is called:

```
build: p.c a.h
    gcc -o build p.c    # target is "build" and it is not the same as "build.exe" which is the output of compilation
```